# Action delegate and multi-thread synchronization

Tags: c#, synchronization

I have field `public Action Update;` which can be called by multiple threads. Also this field can be changed to null etc. Should I make a property and use a lock statement inside it? Or when I setting `Update = new Action (...)` it an atomic operation and it doesn't need a lock?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Setting a reference in C# is an atomic operation, so there is no need for a lock. However you should make the `Update` reference volatile to make sure that it is properly refreshed across all threads when changed:

```
public volatile Action Update;
```

Regardless of threading, it is always best practice to not expose members directly but rather use properties. Then you need to make the backing storage for the property volatile, which rules out auto properties:

```
private volatile Action update;

public Action Update
{
  get { return update; }
  set { update = value; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I felt I need something like this :-)

Comment: Just beware of the possible race condition when checking for null before calling the delegate.

Answer (score 4):

Follow the answer by Anders, but you need to store the value of the variable temporarily in a local variable if you do null-check to avoid race-condition.

Bad example:

```
if(myClass.Update != null)
{
    // Race condition if Update is set to null here by another thread
    myClass.Update();
}
```

Good example:

```
var updateMethod = myClass.Update;
if(updateMethod != null)
{
    // No race condition since we try to call
    // the same value that we checked for null
    updateMethod();
}
```